# Unable to map/bind Mongo BSON to C# class of different shape

Tags: c#, sql, mongodb, deserialization, bson

I'm experimenting with the [C# driver for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) but the documentation is not very good IMO.

I have a document structure that looks something like:

```
{
  _id: 929384
  person: {
   name: 'Joe'
   contact: {
     phones: ["234", "567"],
     emails: ["blah@blah.com"]
  meta-data: .... // (I do not want this in my class)
  address: ....etc
```

I see no point having lots of C# mini classes to mirror the BSON structure, so a class like this is fine

```
public class Person
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string[] phones {get; set;}
  etc...
}
```

In other words it's just a whole lot flatter and without a lot of unnecessary fields.

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. query the equivalent of a NoSQL stored procedure that returns a new structure with aggregations etc.
2. change the way the driver binds

Researching the first option I found a lot about [map/reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) which seems very good for grouping and aggregating data, but I didn't find something that looks like an SQL stored procedure - filtering / changing columns etc.

After much time I found out that the second way is called [Deserialization](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/). I tried looking at the documentation but IMO it doesn't do the best job at explaining.

I need to be able to map `person.contact.phones -> Person.Phones`, I don't know why it should be so complicated.

I am not looking for anyone to do the work for me, this is just a contrived example. I just want to know which of the 2 options is the more correct way (or is there a third) and how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `Phones` property with `[BsonElement("person.contact.phones")]` Attribute?

Comment: yes, it doesn't seem to bind

Comment: You could create a custom deserializer, but that's just abuse. You could definitely use the aggregation framework (google for `$project`). M/R in MongoDB wasn't made for ad-hoc queries so don't go down that road. However, all this really seems to be missing the entire point of MongoDB. If you *want* a mismatch between code and database, why not just stick to SQL? The whole idea of MongoDB is that you don't need to meddle with those annoying details and that the objects in your DB look like your classes in code. If you don't want the classes, why do you want the JSON to look the way it does?